# Knockout JS: Dynamically adding and removing table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout js here.

I have a HTML table and the table has 4 columns. I have button to add a row to table and then remove button against each row to delete it. HTML table as below.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="mbhead">
            <tr class="mbrow">
                <th>Input</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control common-input-text" data-bind="event: { change: $root.addNewItem }">                            
                        <option value="">One</option>
                        <option value="">Two</option>
                        <option value="">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><span class="input-small" data-bind="value: firstName" /></td>
                <td><span class="input-small" data-bind="value: lastName" /></td>
                <td><span class="input-small" data-bind="value: address" /></td>                    
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Row" data-bind="click: removeRow" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addRow" />
```

My knockout as:

```
        (function () {
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    //Empty Row
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);


    self.addRow = function () {
        self.items.push(new Item());            
    };

    self.removeRow = function (data) {
        self.items.remove(data);
    };        
}

var Item = function (fname, lname, address) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(fname);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lname);
    self.address = ko.observable(address);        
};

vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);

})();
```

When I click add row, it adds the first row but gives me console error:

> knockout.js:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: >function (){return removeRow }"
>   Message: removeRow is not defined

When I click add row again it gives me another console error:

> Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

And when I click removeRow nothing happens.

When I comment out the code for removeRow, I am able to add a new row.
Not sure where I am going wrong.

Here is my jsfiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/nz2dtud6/2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the data binding `foreach` the context changes to the context of its childs. To access the context of the parent, you need to add `$parent` to access `removeRow`

```
<td>
    <input type="button" value="Remove Row" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow" class="btn btn-danger" />
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine. One question though, my select and other fields in the row has currently no id associated with it. What needs to be done, so that when I click add row, the new added row fields have different id ie all selects have different ids, textbox/labels if any have different id. Basically my end goal is that once the user is done with adding rows I want to save these. So I wanted to loop through and save.

Comment: Take a look at this binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html At the end all information you need about your items should be stored within the corresponding Item object. I would suggest to create the ids on save to ensure, that they are unique in the database. On loading the rows from your storage, also return the ids to ensure that the correct objects are updated, if you save again.

Comment: Btw. since I am not sure, that is clear: On save it should not be necessary to touch the dom elements, instead use the object lust stored in your viewModel.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it and create separate post if required.

Comment: Paul, can you also look at my post at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285406/knockout-js-get-dropdown-selected-data-and-populate-other-fields . If you can provide some inputs

Answer (score 1):

Since your `<tbody>` defines a new *scope* by using a `foreach: items` binding, you need to use `$parent.removeRow` to refer to the method.

```
<input data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow" type="button" value="Remove Row" />
```

See [BindingContext](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: Can you provide inputs to my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285406/knockout-js-get-dropdown-selected-data-and-populate-other-fields