# Knockout JS: Get dropdown selected data and populate other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Using Knockout JS here.

I have a HTML table and the table has 4 columns. I have button to add a row to table and then remove button against each row to delete it. I also have a dropdown in the first column of this table. The dropdown is populated from the button click event outside the table. Below is my html:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="mbhead">
      <tr class="mbrow">
       <th>Input</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ddl, optionsText: 'name', value: $parent.selectedColumnValue, optionsCaption: '--Select--',  event: { change: $parent.ddlChanged }">                          
                    </select>
  </td>
  <td><span class="input-small" data-bind="value: firstName" /></td>
  <td><span class="input-small" data-bind="value: lastName" /></td>
  <td><span class="input-small" data-bind="value: address" /></td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" value="Remove Row" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow" class="btn btn-danger" />
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addRow" />
 <input type="submit" value="Get Data" data-bind="click: GetData" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

My knockout code can be seen in the jsfiddle link as below.

What I am looking for is:

When the user selects the dropdown the selected dropdown text gets populated to  that rows one column and the value gets populated to that rows other columns/cell.

My Issue:

1.) I am not able to get the selected text and selected value from the dropdown

When the dropdown selected index change event is fired the event param has the below value as seen in console:

> firstName : ƒ c()
>
> lastName: ƒ c()
>
> address : ƒ c()
>
> **proto** : Object

2.) Secondly I don't know how I could update other column values based on the dropdown selection.

The json that gets binded to dropdown is like below:

```
'[{"FirstName":"Alex","LastName":"Sanders","Address":123},{"FirstName":"Sam","LastName":"Billings","Address":"Mahony Street"}]';
```

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/njbyumrs/12/

Inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some parent and level stuff mixed up, and your table was binding on `value` instead of `text`. I moved the drop down binding, `selectedValue` to `Item` since it's at the row level and not the parent level. I used the KO `with` binding to show the values inside `selectedValue` for that part of the HTML.

I also added a `<pre>` tag with the KO values so you can see what happens as you interact with it and the KO model data changes.

Side note: The three properties in `Item` don't need to be observable in this demo as the values do not change while on the screen.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  //Empty Row
  self.items = ko.observableArray([new Item()]);
  self.ddl = ko.observableArray();  

  self.addRow = function() {
    self.items.push(new Item());
  };

  self.removeRow = function(data) {
    self.items.remove(data);
  };
  self.GetData = function() {
    if (self.ddl().length === 0) {
      var item1 = new Item("Alex", "Sanders", "Maple Street");
      self.ddl.push(item1);
      var item2 = new Item("Sam", "Billings", "Mahony Street");
      self.ddl.push(item2);
    }
  }
}

var Item = function(fname, lname, address) {
  var self = this;
  self.firstName = ko.observable(fname);
  self.lastName = ko.observable(lname);
  self.address = ko.observable(address);
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
};

vm = new ViewModel()
vm.GetData();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="mbhead">
    <tr class="mbrow">
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
      <td><select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ddl, optionsText: 'firstName', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: '--Select--'"> </select></td>
      <td data-bind="with: selectedValue">
        <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
      </td>
      <td data-bind="with: selectedValue">
        <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
      </td>
      <td data-bind="with: selectedValue">
        <span data-bind="text: address"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Remove Row" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow" class="btn btn-danger" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">  
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addRow" />
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe.  While this works when having ddl outside table but my specific requirement calls for having it inside the table. I might have another column with another dropdown as well. I was trying to create my table based on this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html but couldnt get that setup working. How hard is to update the above code having a ddl inside.

Comment: I've made those changes.

Comment: Thanks Joe for all the help. I have updated my code and made it fit for my requirements and it works fine. Just one last question before we close those. I have added another static dropdown column and another output column in the table. How can we set the output column value based on the first dropdown and second dropdown value. I tried to create a computed function in the Item object but it did not made any effect. I have updated my js fiddle as: https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/rtb6kxk6/3/  Again thanks for looking into.

Comment: The source of the second drop down (`options`) can be a computed that filters the array on the current value of the first drop down.

Comment: That would populate the second dropdown with computed values. I want the last column to have computed values from the selection of first and second dropdown.

Comment: You can set the `value` observable for the receiving drop down in code. As long as it's one of the options, it will show it as selected.

Comment: Sorry for taking up so much of your time but I have made the changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/rtb6kxk6/3/  As you said I have added selectedGender as the value of the second dropdown and made that observable. For the text to be displayed I have used this selectedGender as databind-with. And then I am trying to concatenate this value to one of the column values. But it gives me error address is not defined.

Comment: Some progress here. I am able to populate my output column with the value from second dropdown. See my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/rtb6kxk6/3/  But the only thing left is concatenating this with value of first dropdown selection. When I try to concatenate the input selected + self.selectedGender() . The input is always undefined

Comment: Your JSFiddle link is to the one from yesterday, so I can't see what you mean about the concatenating bug. If you can update it, I can take a look, but perhaps this is another question, as it sounds like your original question has been answered and you have additional help you need.

Comment: Looks like I had overwritten a fiddle. I have updated the fiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/uf708rvz/19/ If you click add row, then click add data and then select from the first dropdown. It will fill firstname, and last name columns. On selection of second dropdown I want to concatenate the address with the value from first dropdown.  Sorry will create a new post for future queries.

Comment: Fixed your fiddle so the second drop down is concatenated to the first name. https://jsfiddle.net/joewilson/uf708rvz/21/

Comment: Thanks Joe for the all the help.

Comment: I have another question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433044/knockout-js-creating-dynamic-table-columns . Would appreciate if you can look at that as I am not getting good help on that.