# Knockout JS: Get Textbox data from Table under for-each binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using knockout js here:

Following on from my post at [Knockout JS: Creating dynamic table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433044/knockout-js-creating-dynamic-table-columns)

I have managed to somehow create dynamic columns in knockout. So when the user clicks add row it adds a row to the table. What I am currently stuck is at how to get the data with what is entered in the textboxes in my table. Say for ex I have 4 columns and adding a row would create 4 textbox in the table. When the user enters the data in those textbox I want to loop and get all the data that is entered and save.

Here is the jsfiddle that I have managed to create. 
https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/L3pjhk0z/6/

My valuesData is always empty here:

```
"valuesData": [
{}
```

What updates do I need to make in my fiddle to get all the data. May be in the json form as

```
{
  "col1": "1", 
  "col2": "2"
   ....and so on depending on the columns
}
```

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Your textboxes aren't bound to anything

Comment: @ChrisNevill I have updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/L3pjhk0z/15/  It just gives me the first value typed in my textbox. And when I type in first, the same gets copied over to the rest textboxes. I want to create a json as mentioned above in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input fields didn't map to your value data.

My code differs in some points of yours. To ensure, that `self.columnNames` does not have more columns than `ValuesData` I created a static object `ValuesData.columns` which contains all relevant column definitions. The observables for the single columns are created dynamically as soon as you click on `addRow`.

```js
(function() {
  var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.valuesData = ko.observableArray();

    self.columns = ko.computed(function() {
      if (self.valuesData().length === 0)
        return [];

      return ValuesData.columns;
    });


    self.addRow = function() {
      self.valuesData.push(new ValuesData());
    };

    self.Save = function() {
      alert('Data:')
    };

    self.removeRow = function(data) {
      self.valuesData.remove(data);
    };
  }

  // Dynamic values.
  var ValuesData = function(siid, comment) {
    var self = this;

    // Add observables dynamically for all relevant columns.
    for (var i = 0; i < ValuesData.columns.length; i++) {
      var column = ValuesData.columns[i];
      self[column.Property] = ko.observable(column.InitialValue)
    }
  };

  // Basic column definition.
  ValuesData.columns = [{
      Caption: 'SIID',
      Property: 'SIID',
      InitialValue: undefined
    },
    {
      Caption: 'Column 1',
      Property: 'Col1',
      InitialValue: undefined
    },
    {
      Caption: 'Column 2',
      Property: 'Col2',
      InitialValue: 'banana'
    },
    {
      Caption: 'Comment',
      Property: 'Comment',
      InitialValue: undefined
    }
  ]

  vm = new ViewModel()
  ko.applyBindings(vm);

  // add initial row.
  vm.addRow();


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- NEW: use ko foreach with 'as' to have an alias for accessing $data. -->
    <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: columns, as: 'column'}">
      <th> <span data-bind="text: column.Caption"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: valuesData, as: 'rowData'}">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $parent.columns, as: 'column' }">
      <!-- NEW: bind to the corresponding property/observable in ValuesData -->
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-bind="textInput: rowData[column.Property]" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Remove Row" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow" class="btn btn-danger" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addRow" />
  <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: Save" />
</div>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(valuesData, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your answer.  I will look to integrate this within my code. I have a question though. You have defined ValuesData.columns outside the viewmodel. How can this be defined inside the view model. Basically I have would have a comma separated list of columns inside my view model. I can create the json as you have from the columns list but how not sure how to define ValuesData inside my viewmodel. Sorry am pretty new to KO so pardon me if this is basic.

Comment: I have got this working now with my changes. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/4djn2zee/  One last question though. How can I add validations to only certain columns textboxes. If I only want numbers only on certain columns ( based on column name). I can create a separate post for this if you want.

Comment: I am having an issue getting value  from the observable. See my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556448/knockout-js-creating-json-from-viewmodel-observable-array Would appreciate if you help me with that since its constructed as per your answer here